# Custom config params in flyway java migration

Tags: java, migration, flyway

Is there anyway to pass our own config params to Java Flyway migration.

My usecase is to do some migrations and generate the output in csv file and upload it to S3.

S3 props are environment specific, I would like to keep them in configuration. flyway's `context` object has Configuration which doesn't have an option to keep our own configurations. Instead we can just keep the predefined configs. Is there any workaround to pass such config to Java Migration classes.

Comment: Would system properties from flyway's command line or maven flyway plugin work for you? I don't seem to find another way to use's Flyway's configuration objects to get your S3 bucket config.

Comment: Yes, We use flyway docker and sent these config in env variables to container thus java can use them

Comment: May be thats the only solution to this issue for now. env variables or system properties and use in Java Migration classes.